# Natural parameterization of the following curve

Tags: geometry, differential

The given curve is: $ 27 x^{2} = 4 y^{3} $.
I have to find the natural parameterization.
First, I parameterized the curve:
$$ 27 x^2 = 4 y^3 $$
$$ x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{27} y^3} $$
What should I do when I have two possibilities?
I took one possibility, for example: $$ x = \sqrt{\frac{4}{27} y^3} $$
Parameterization: $$ \alpha (t) = (\sqrt{\frac{4}{27} t^3},t) $$

The other steps:
$$ \alpha ' (t) = (\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{3}},1) $$
$$ || \alpha ' (t) || = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{t+3} $$
$$s(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{u+3} du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\frac{2}{3}(t+3)^{\frac{3}{2}}- 2\sqrt{3})$$
Did I go wrong at some point? It became too complicated, so I need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did fine. Now, you invert $s$:$$s^{-1}(t)=\frac{3\sqrt[3]{(t+2)^2}}{\sqrt[3]4}-3.$$So, a natural parametrisation of your curve is$$t\mapsto\alpha\bigl(s^{-1}(t)\bigr)=\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{2(t+2)^2}-2\right)^{\frac32}}{\sqrt2},\left(\frac{3\sqrt[3]{(t+2)^2}}{\sqrt[3]4}-3\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: one question, what should I do with the $ \pm $ ? Should I do both cases?

Comment: Note the your curve has acorner at $(0,0)$. THerefore, there is na way you can obtain the whole curve by this process. But you can get a natural parametrization of the other half adding a $-$ sign to the second component of my answer.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Right: cusp. I couldn't remember the right word and that's why I used “corner” instead. The $x$ was typo, which I have edited. Thank you.

Comment: The curve is $y=|x|^{2/3}$ $\>(-\infty<x<\infty)$. It has a characteristic cusp, not a "corner", at the origin. Concerning your comment: The curve is lying completely in the upper half plane.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter It's a pity that I can't edit that comment. The $-$ sign should be put on the **first** component, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If we write $x=2t^3$ then we have $$\dfrac{y^3}{27}=\dfrac{x^2}{4}=t^6\implies y=3t^2.$$

Thus we get $$\alpha(t)=(2t^3,3t^2),$$ which is a nice parametrization to get the length of the curve.